# Comparing objects by value

Tags: javascript, image, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I have a javascript game that uses *drag and drop* of images to create words. Currently if the word has repeating letters, I have to name the letters differently:

```
Example word: Alphabet,
images: a.png, l.png, p.png, h.png, a1.png, b.png, e.png and t.png.
```

As you can imagine when you drag `a.png` to spell the word, it has to be on its own defined block or it wont lock in place.

How can i edit the script to use the same image more than once and be able to drag on any of the correct placements.

See this fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q89Ck/

```
<script defer="defer">
  function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var assetDir = 'http://kidnplay.co.uk/spelling/alphabet/';
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = assetDir + sources[src];
    }
  }
  function isNearOutline(animal, outline) {
    var a = animal;
    var o = outline;
    var ax = a.getX();
    var ay = a.getY();

    if(ax > o.x - 20 && ax < o.x + 20 && ay > o.y - 20 && ay < o.y + 20) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  function drawBackground(background, backImg, text) {
    var canvas = background.getCanvas();
    var context = background.getContext();

    context.drawImage(backImg, 0, 0);
    context.font = '18pt georgia,palatino';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    context.fillText(text, background.getStage().getWidth() / 2, 32);
  }
  function initStage(images) {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 940,
      height: 600
    });
    var background = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var animalLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var animalShapes = [];
    var score = 0;

    // image positions
    var animals = {
      a: {
        x: 50,
        y: 70
      },
      e: {
        x: 150,
        y: 70
      },
      b: {
        x: 250,
        y: 70
      },
      t: {
        x: 350,
        y: 70
      },
      a2: {
        x: 450,
        y: 70
      },
      p: {
        x: 550,
        y: 70
      },
      l: {
        x: 650,
        y: 70
      },
      h: {
        x: 750,
        y: 70
      },
    };


    var outlines = {
      a_black: {
        x: 30,
        y: 300
      },
      l_black: {
        x: 135,
        y: 300
      },
      p_black: {
        x: 240,
        y: 300
      },
      h_black: {
        x: 345,
        y: 300
      },
      a2_black: {
        x: 450,
        y: 300
      },
      b_black: {
        x: 555,
        y: 300
      },
      e_black: {
        x: 660,
        y: 300
      },
      t_black: {
        x: 765,
        y: 300
      },
    };

    // create draggable animals
    for(var key in animals) {
      // anonymous function to induce scope
      (function() {
        var privKey = key;
        var anim = animals[key];

        var animal = new Kinetic.Image({
          image: images[key],
          x: anim.x,
          y: anim.y,
          draggable: true
        });

        animal.createImageHitRegion();

        animal.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
          animalLayer.draw();
        });
        /*
         * check if animal is in the right spot and
         * snap into place if it is
         */
        animal.on('dragend', function() {
          var outline = outlines[privKey + '_black'];
          if(!animal.inRightPlace && isNearOutline(animal, outline)) {
            animal.setPosition(outline.x, outline.y);
            animalLayer.draw();
            animal.inRightPlace = true;

            if(++score >= 8) {
              var text = 'Well done! The correct word is alphabet!'
              drawBackground(background, images.back, text);
            }

            // disable drag and drop
            setTimeout(function() {
              animal.setDraggable(false);
            }, 50);
          }
        });
        // make animal glow on mouseover
        animal.on('mouseover', function() {
          animal.setImage(images[privKey + '_glow']);
          animalLayer.draw();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });
        // return animal on mouseout
        animal.on('mouseout', function() {
          animal.setImage(images[privKey]);
          animalLayer.draw();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        });

        animal.on('dragmove', function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });

        animalLayer.add(animal);
        animalShapes.push(animal);
      })();
    }

    // create animal outlines
    for(var key in outlines) {
      // anonymous function to induce scope
      (function() {
        var imageObj = images[key];
        var out = outlines[key];

        var outline = new Kinetic.Image({
          image: imageObj,
          x: out.x,
          y: out.y
        });

        animalLayer.add(outline);
      })();
    }

    stage.add(background);
    stage.add(animalLayer);

    drawBackground(background, images.back, 'Rearrange the letters to spell the word');
  }

  var sources = {
    back: 'back.png',
    a: 'a.png',
    a_glow: 'a-glow.png',
    a_black: 'a-black.png',
    b: 'b.png',
    b_glow: 'b-glow.png',
    b_black: 'b-black.png',
    e: 'e.png',
    e_glow: 'e-glow.png',
    e_black: 'e-black.png',        
    h: 'h.png',
    h_glow: 'h-glow.png',
    h_black: 'h-black.png',
    l: 'l.png',
    l_glow: 'l-glow.png',
    l_black: 'l-black.png', 
    p: 'p.png',
    p_glow: 'p-glow.png',
    p_black: 'p-black.png',
    t: 't.png',
    t_glow: 't-glow.png',
    t_black: 't-black.png',
    a2: 'a2.png',
    a2_glow: 'a2-glow.png',
    a2_black: 'a2-black.png',
  };
  loadImages(sources, initStage);


</script>
```

Comment: Don't put the x/y positions in the animals, just put a letter there, and also put the letters in the outlines. Then `isNearOutline` can loop over all the outlines looking for the ones with the same letter, and check whether the animal is within its outline.

Answer (score 0):

*For using same image for both As:*
You need to separate out the dependency of image names with the key you use.
One possible way is to add another attribute in the arrays which have the value of actual alphabet and use that value to source from your images array. This basically solves your issue with using same images for 2 variables.

*For snapping either A's in either of the possible positions:*
You can use suggestion from Barmar in the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

To allow fitting either “A” into an outline, assign both the animal and outline a “letter” property.

Add a “letter” property to each animal object:

```
animal.letter=”A”;
```

Add a “correct” letter property to each outline object:

```
outline.letter=”A”;
```

Then you can check if a correct letter is in a specified outline:

```
if( outline.letter == animal.letter ) {  

    // a valid animal is in the outline

}
```

This also allows you to use the same A.png in both the “A-animals”.